# Putextra keep sending the first entered data

Tags: java, android, android-intent

This is the function which is used to send data to the Main activity.

```
public void sendData(){
        String name = Bookname.getText().toString();
        String  number = Integer.parseInt(Bookpage.getText().toString());
        String description = Booknote.getText().toString();
        Intent back = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        back.putExtra("Bookname",name);
        back.putExtra("Booknote",description);
        back.putExtra("number",number);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, back);
        finish();
    }
```

This is where I used the function.

```
 @Override
    public boolean  onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.Color_picker){
            Toast.makeText(this, "ColoRS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.Check_icon){
            sendData();
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is how I get the strings in the Main Activity

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Ref c1 = new Ref(data.getStringExtra("Bookname"), data.getStringExtra("Booknote"),data.getIntExtra("number",0),data.getIntExtra("color", Color.RED));
            adapter.add(c1);

        }
    }
```

My problem is that the data are only written once and when the function should be sending different data it sends the same data as the first entered data.

Comment: how are you retrieving this data in the MainActivity?

Comment: I'm using an override method which is onActivityResult to get the extra intent. I've changed my implementation of sending the data from an onClick on a button to an item on onOptionsItemSelected and that's when the problem occurred.

Comment: can you post that code on onActivityResult?

Comment: I've updated the original post and included the function.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more your problem "when the function should be sending different data ". Your code seem fine to me

Comment: code looks fine buddy.

Comment: I'm sending the data from an activity to the Main Activity which contains a Recyclerview that holds all the entered data. The problem is that the first item on the Recyclerview contains the correct data entered by the user, but when the user is adding a new item on the Recyclerview the data entered will be overwritten with the same data as the first item.

Comment: This is what's happening.    https://imgur.com/a/EhUErVi

Comment: The problem probably with your adding item code. Can you add your item add related code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send your `activityOnResult` with 1 as `REQUEST_CODE` is OK

The only problem I guess you are having (I do not have much more information) is since I see and adapter, I guess you should call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to see changes on your "list"?

Also you can "clear" the `intent`, to avoid duplicated stuff, every time you go to `onActivityResult()` you can do this `getIntent().removeExtra("key");` to ensure, next time will come different data.

If you do this, you have to do the other logic good to work with this...

Comment: @Skeptic94 I'm glat to hear that :), mark this question as a correct if it helped :)

Comment: When I added adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() on my onActivityResult method it solved the problem. but I'm really curious to why it used to work just fine on my previous implementation which is sending the data back with a button click instead of an action bar item without adding adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().